# Insert Rows From Excel into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel, vba

I am working on an insert from Excel 2010 into SQL Server 2008. I have been able to successfully insert a single cell value into a SQL table from excel using a push button. Now I am trying to insert many rows. I am trying to use a single loop to iterate and insert the values. My code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Private Conn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim val1 As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConnString As String

For i = 1 To 2
 Cells(i, 1) = "val1"
Next i

'This will create the string to connect.
sConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};Data Source=**;Initial Catalog = **;Trusted_Connection =yes;"

'Create Connection and the Recordset Objects.
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection

'Open the Connection in Order to Execute.
Conn.Open sConnString

Conn.Execute ("insert into TestTable(TestColumn) Values(" & val1 & ")")

'Clean
If CBool(Conn.State And adStateOpen) Then Conn.Close
    Set Conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am inserting a value into the table, but its not the values that are in cells A1:A2. Can someone tell me how my loop and my insert statement is wrong? Is there a better way to handle this. I know I am only using 2 rows at the moment but I will be inserting 1100 rows so a loop or iterative process is needed I'm assuming.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What values are you getting instead of `A1:A2`?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting val1 incorrectly.  Change:

```
Cells(i, 1) = "val1"
```

to

```
val1 = Cells(i, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Conn As AD

ODB.Connection

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim val(1100) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer


    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sConnString As String


    For i = 1 To 2
     val(i) = Cells(i,1).value





    'This will create the string to connect.

    sConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};Data Source=**;Initial Catalog = **;Trusted_Connection =yes;"



    'Create Connection and the Recordset Objects.

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection




    'Open the Connection in Order to Execute.

    Conn.Open sConnString

    Conn.Execute ("insert into TestTable(TestColumn) Values(" & val(i) & ")")





        'Clean
        If CBool(Conn.State And adStateOpen) Then Conn.Close
        Set Conn = Nothing

    Next i

    End Sub
```